# Is the Canaanite woman from Tyre and Sidon a Gentile or not?

Tags: genealogy

As far as I know the Canaanite woman, she is a gentile, yes?

Or is she from Ham's son's lineage Canaan etc?

What makes a gentile?

Is it only not being in one of the twelve tribes of Israel?

Or something else?

Comment: To questions 1) and 4) : Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is the Canaanite woman from Tyre and Sidon a Gentile or not?**

The short answer is **yes**. She is a Gentile.

It is quite possible that she is a descendant  of Canaan and thus [Ham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_(son_of_Noah)).

She is not not of Jewish decent and she is not a [Samaritan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritans). Greeks were considered to be [Gentiles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentile) to both the Jews and the Samaritans.

> The Exorcism of the Syrophoenician woman's daughter is one of the miracles of Jesus in the Gospels and is recounted in the Gospel of Mark in Chapter 7 (Mark 7:24-30) and in the Gospel of Matthew in Chapter 15 (Matthew 15:21-28). In Matthew, the story is recounted as the healing of a Canaanite woman's daughter. According to both accounts, Jesus exorcised the woman's daughter whilst travelling in the region of Tyre and Sidon, on account of the faith shown by the woman.
>
> The woman described in the miracle, the Syrophoenician woman (Mark 7:26) is also called a "Canaanite" (Matthew 15:22) and is an unidentified New Testament woman from the region of Tyre and Sidon. "The woman is ... described as **Syrophoenician by race**. It is unclear whether Mark seeks to distinguish between a [Phoenician](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenicia)from Syria and one from northern Africa or between someone living in the coastal area of Syria and someone living in the central part." Her other notable characteristic is her non-Jewish status: **the Gospel of Mark adds that she is a Greek** (Greek: Ελληνις).
>
> The third century pseudo-Clementine homily refers to her name as Justa and her daughter's name as Berenice. - [Exorcism of the Syrophoenician woman's daughter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exorcism_of_the_Syrophoenician_woman%27s_daughter)

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if the event was tied to the loaves and fishes afterwards being a symbolic first gentile "miracle" and that the bread and fishes was another metaphorical example of Jesus now accepting gentiles, but it seems it may not link if the woman is related etc.  Odd, because all people outside of the "12" should be gentile if all people descend from Noah's family in some way after the flood etc? Though it says some either Nephilim or other names, Children of Anak were alive after flood so probably more people etc?

Answer (score 0):

Deuteronmy 7 gives an insight into the origin of gentile, in essence NOT Yahweh's people...furthermore in the greek text the term for "Gentile" is ἔθνος [Strongs 1484], literally meaning of the nations. It [gentile] depending on context can be referred to in scripture as ειδωλολάτρης [Strongs 1495] meaning idol worshipper...

Interestingly the woman is challenged by Yeshua when he tells her "I was sent for the lost sheep of the house of Israel", she asked again and Yeshua said, "it is not right to take the childrens bread and throw it to the dogs.
She acknowledged she was a dog and that even dogs [like her] know their master [Lord].

I might encourage to read through Exodus, Deuteronomy and Numbers, then Genesis [Chapter 36] as I believe the Word of Elohim reveals prophetically Jew and Gentile through Joshua and Caleb, the only 2 from the Exodus from Egypt who entered the Promised Land [Shadow of the Kingdom of Heaven].
You will discover that while Caleb is recorded in Numbers 13 as of the line of Judah, you will discover that Caleb is in fact a gentile [proselyte] grafted in, of the the Kennizites [descendants of Esau].
Joshua is from the tribe of Ephraim which ultimately is the representation of the 10 lost tribes....
Now we begin to see Gods signs...when we then read Ezekiel 36,37 and Jeremiah 31:31, the New Covenant [the Holy Spirit of God in us], it is for the fulfillment of Gods Covenant Promise to Israel [Prince of Yahweh]...thus the lost [dispersed] sheep of the House of Israel.

Put another way, Israel [Gods people] are those in Covenant Relationship, born of his seed, through his circumcision of our hearts.

May Yahweh bless you and keep you.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).